# jquery animate scrollTop function is not working in internet explore

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am using this code:

```
$('#goto_introduction_divcontent').click(function(){    
    var targetOffset = $('#introduction_div').offset().top;    
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:targetOffset}, 'slow');    
    if ($.browser.msie){    
        document.documentElement.scrollTop = targetOffset;  
    }  
});
```

But this not working in Internet Explorer. My jsFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/ThxcG/).

Comment: Please specify the browser version when you think it is a browser specific issue. btw It worked fine on FF3.6 and IE8.

Comment: in chrome and firebox its working fine, but in IE7 and IE9 not working

Answer (score 45):

This works for me in IE8+:

```
$('body, html').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
```

Maybe your IF statement is throwing things off?

Comment: Life saver! I tried every single combination of window.parent, window.parent.document, window.parent.document.$("body") etc. but hadn't thought to try html until I saw this - html works in IE, body works in all other browsers we support :)

Comment: I can attest I see this working in multiple browsers. I'm concerned that it might not be as efficient as it could be and that perhaps there's some way to check animation support first, and select the tag accordingly. But since i don't have the time for that right now, upvote! Works in a pinch!

Comment: The `html` selector did the trick for me in IE11. Thanks loads.

Comment: I have use this and its working for me in all the version of IE from 7